# Sub-classing a Python list for a SQLAlchemy pandas.series mapping

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a convenient SQLALchemy mapping of `pandas.Series`. I have a top-level class `Super` which I want to have an `entries` attribute that essentially maps a `pandas.Series`:

```
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, DeclarativeBase, Session
import pandas as pd

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Super(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'super_objects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    entries = relationship("SeriesEntry")
```

Then I have a `SeriesEntry` class to hold the individual entries of `Series`:

```
class SeriesEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'series_entries'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer)
    index_value = Column(String)
    super_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('super_objects.id'))
```

I believe it is not necessary to define an intermediate table between 'super_objects' and 'series_entries', so I am trying to get away with just making my `Series` a Python abstraction without a SQLAlchemy mapping to a table:

```
class Series(list):
    def __init__(self, pandas_series):
        for idxval, val in pandas_series.items():
            self.append(SeriesEntry(value=val, index_value=idxval))
```

I sub-class `list` because that makes the whole thing work, so I can:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
session = Session(engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

my_series = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
super_instance = Super(name='Example Super Object')
super_instance.entries = Series(my_series)

session.add(super_instance)
session.commit()
```

**Now my actual question:**
I would like to make a convenient way to convert `Series` back to `pandas.Series` and thought of implementing a method `to_pd_series` in `Series` to do this. Now, my challenge is that the contents of `super_instance.entries` is seen as a list of `SeriesEntry` (which it also is), but I would like it to be seen as a `Series` object so I can call the `to_pd_series` method I am planning, on it.
I am guessing this is due to the way I implement `Series`and maybe there are more things I can add to make this work? To me this feels very much like programming in C where I have some structured data in memory pointed to by some pointer and then I can simply typecast it to some struct datatype I have defined with the structure that my data in memory follows. I have just never tried doing something like this in Python. How can I make this work?

Comment: I am guessing that the issue is configuring the `Super` class correctly map entries as a `Series` instead of merely seeing a list-like sequence of `SeriesEntry`. I could do this by defining `Series` as a SQLAlchemy mapping class (inheriting from Base), but my understand is that this has to create a corresponding table in the database. I would like to avoid that intermediate table in the database and make `Series` purely an abstraction on the Python side.